# How to get username and role after login using ASP.NET? (integrated aspnetdb into my database)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I made ​​one website using ASP.NET, it manages students.I have built a database of students and aspnetdb database integration.When I login to get username and role, but do not know how.I need this to each member, they will have one single function, see timetable and their own information ...
I want to know about this earlier. Hopefully someone will help me. Thank you!

Comment: If have have integrated aspnetdb into your database then I'm guessing you want to use the SQL-based membership and role providers? [This](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/02/24/ASP.NET-2.0-Membership_2C00_-Roles_2C00_-Forms-Authentication_2C00_-and-Security-Resources-.aspx) link is a bit old but it should provide enough relevant content and walkthrough to get you started....

Comment: I still have not found what I want.For example: I have one procedure, it helps to show the point of have StudentId = UserName after login.What I want to ask is can use these commands to get the UserName of the person.

Comment: Hi there, for the community to help you effectively it would assist if you can put any working code which you have inside your question (e.g. edit your question so your code is shown) and perhaps show/comment in your code where you want it to do a certain thing or where it's not doing what you expect.

Comment: In fact it is one of only a few short statements but I do not know where to find it.I hope people understand what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your login in the identity linked to current thread, identity implement `IIdentity` interface

link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.security.principal.iidentity.aspx

Firstly you get your `CurrentPrincipal`, parse your principal and return your identity

link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.threading.thread.currentprincipal.aspx

link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.security.principal.iprincipal.aspx

Note : you can override your identity and principal, but this suppose that you have added your principal with identity to current thread

Comment: I still have not found what I want.For example: I have one procedure, it helps to show the point of have StudentId = UserName after login.What I want to ask is can use these commands to get the UserName of the person.

Comment: In fact it is one of only a few short statements but I do not know where to find it.I hope people understand what I mean.